# an error while connecting node js with mongoDB

Tags: node.js, mongoose, mern

In the Backend folder, I created a server.js file.

```
const express = require('express');
const cors = require('cors');
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

require('dotenv').config();

const app = express();
const port = process.env.PORT || 5000;

app.use(cors());
app.use(express.json());

//connect with mongoDB
const uri = process.env.ATLAS_URI;
mongoose.connect(uri, { useNewUrlParser: true, useCreateIndex: true }
);
const connection = mongoose.connection;
connection.once('open', () => {
  console.log("MongoDB database connection established successfully");
})

//import routes
//const exercisesRouter = require('./routes/exercises');
//const usersRouter = require('./routes/users');

//use routes
//app.use('/exercises', exercisesRouter);
//app.use('/users', usersRouter);

app.listen(port, () => {
    console.log(`Server is running on port: ${port}`);
});
```

after I entered **nodemon server** command.

Here What printed in the terminel

---

[nodemon] 2.0.20
[nodemon] to restart at any time, enter `rs`
[nodemon] watching path(s): *.*
[nodemon] watching extensions: js,mjs,json
[nodemon] starting `node server.js`
(node:92140) [MONGOOSE] DeprecationWarning: Mongoose: the `strictQuery` option will be switched back to `false` by default in Mongoose 7. Use `mongoose.set('strictQuery', false);` if you want to prepare for this change. Or use `mongoose.set('strictQuery', true);` to suppress this warning.
(Use `node --trace-deprecation ...` to show where the warning was created)
node:events:491
throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
^

Error: listen EADDRINUSE: address already in use :::5000
at Server.setupListenHandle [as _listen2] (node:net:1733:16)
at listenInCluster (node:net:1781:12)
at Server.listen (node:net:1869:7)
at Function.listen (/Users/masterlwa/Desktop/exercise-tracker/backend/node_modules/express/lib/application.js:635:24)
at Object. (/Users/masterlwa/Desktop/exercise-tracker/backend/server.js:32:5)
at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1218:14)
at Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1272:10)
at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1081:32)
at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:922:12)
at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (node:internal/modules/run_main:81:12)
Emitted 'error' event on Server instance at:
at emitErrorNT (node:net:1760:8)
at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:82:21) {
code: 'EADDRINUSE',
errno: -48,
syscall: 'listen',
address: '::',
port: 5000
}

Node.js v18.13.0
[nodemon] app crashed - waiting for file changes before starting...

---

Currently, I do not have an idea regarding how to fix this. How to fix this?

Comment: port 5000 that you are using to run your express app is already occupied by other process in your system. Once try changing port number.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

seems like port 5000 is alreay in used by another app, try to change port to 5001 or something else